# fix error: no such partition. grub rescue WITHOUT cd drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, asus

I'm trying to completely remove UBuntu from my Asus Eee PC 1015PEM because I'm giving it to a relative. I thought it would be as simple as deleting the partition it was stored on using Windows Disk Management, but I was wrong.

Now whenever I try to boot I get "error: no such partition" and on the next line it says "grub rescue:"

I've googled and looked everywhere but all solutions involve using the Windows installation disk, however, this Eee PC (netbook) doesn't have a CD drive, and that is therefore not an option.

I have a USB with the Windows 7 installation iso "burned" to it, I just have no idea how to boot into it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

Windows isn't good at recognising other OS's. If it isn't working, blank the disk off completely with `sudo cat /dev/zero >/dev/sda` from a Ubuntu USB; let it run for a few seconds, to overwrite the boot sectors, then quit with -c.

Windows will then see an unpartitioned blank drive & should run. If not, it's likely to be a problem with your Windows USB - does it work elsewhere?

Comment: EDIT: I created a Ubuntu Live USB, plugged into the netbook, and turned it on. Still won't boot from it. Just sits there with the grub rescue and the error.

I'm going to create a Ubuntu live USB right now, and go from there. Hopefully this works. Will post back when done. Thanks for the response!